# Is there Saiku Reporting plugin for Pentaho BI Server 5.0.1?

Tags: pentaho, saiku

Saiku Reporting 1.0-GA is available here: http://mgiepz.github.io/saiku-reporting

As mentioned in the installation instructions:

> To put Saiku-Reports under the ACL, add `.adhoc` to the `acl-files` in
>   pentaho.xml

I have the previous release 4.8 and in the pentaho.xml file there is a block.

/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho.xml:

```
<!-- 
  acl-files tag was added in support of PPP-130 

  * Allow specification of ACLs on .url files

  * Allow specification of files acl-able to be
    in the configuration

  Usage: List the file extensions of files allowed to have
  acls. This is a performance tuning exercise since any file
  with an extension in this list can have ACLs applied.
-->

<acl-files>xaction,url,prpt,prpti,xdash,xcdf</acl-files>
```

For version 5.0.1 this block is missing.

I did as instructed, but the plugin Saiku Reporting is not available in 
Pentaho BI Server CE 5.0.1.

In the upper right corner of the screen on the page `/pentaho/Home` I see the following:

> Thank you!
>
> Our Kickstarter for Saiku Reporting has been fully funded. This is
>   great news for the Saiku platform and will allow us to build out a
>   great new Saiku Reporting product with the help from our community.
>   Stay tuned for more updates.

Does that means that while the plugin is not available?

Where can I find Saiku Reporting plugin for Pentaho BI Server 5? Maybe there is some other way to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **download & install** saiku plugin from marketplace.
after reaching marketplace don't select download button directly. default it has selected for enterprise version.
so select community from drop-down and then start downloading.
once you download you need to **follow the instruction for configuring it**.
simple steps like register it and place the licence file into respected folder.(you will get one pop-up with detail instruction) follow that.

after doing this changes you will get saiku option while you will click on create new.